# Android - GPS location does not update after register

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

I am making an application that samples data periodically. I have trouble getting GPS data for some reason.
Here is what I got:

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Code:

```
public class GPSWrapper implements ListenerWrapper {
    public static final int SAMPLES = 10;
    public static final int GPS_SENS_TYPE = -1;
    public static final String GPS_SENS_NAME = "gps";
    private LocationManager mLocManager;

    public GPSWrapper(LocationManager locationManager){
        mLocManager = locationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void sampleSensor() {
        if (mLocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new GPSDataCollector());
        }
        if (mLocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new GPSDataCollector());
        }
    }

    public void unregister(GPSDataCollector collector) {
        mLocManager.removeUpdates(collector);
    }

    private class GPSDataCollector implements LocationListener{
        public ArrayList<String> m_sensorData;

        public GPSDataCollector(){
            m_sensorData = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            double altitude = location.getAltitude();
            m_sensorData.add(latitude + ":" + longitude + ":" + altitude);
            DataCollector.getInstance().fillData(GPS_SENS_TYPE, m_sensorData);
            m_sensorData.clear();
            if (m_sensorData.size() >= SAMPLES) {
                unregister(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    }
}
```

The issue is, I am not getting ANY updates whatsoever.
I tried this code on 3 different devices, and no results at all.
I tried using breakpoints to make sure the 'onLocationChanged' methods get called, but they aren't.
I went through multiple questions in StackOverflow, and I have failed to find any solution.

I would like to reiterate that I have no issues with null location, the function does not get called AT ALL.

I tested this code while walking outside for several minutes, so satellite reception is not the issue. The GPS tracker icon was on the entire time.

Answer (score 1):

when you call `requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new GPSDataCollector());` you request for location updates every 0 milliseconds AND every 0 meters. pass 1000 as the second parameter to get the updates each second. And of course GPS signal must be available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know what the parameters mean, this was out of desperation since I couldn't get any readings, so I set it to "just update whenever".
Would setting it to sample every second really make a difference here? I'm not getting ANY updates at all

Comment: there is a post here, on stackoverflow, about that "just update whenever" doesn't work on some devices. Apart from that your code looks ok, may be some device issue. Check it works in other app. Check android settings. try to add (if not)  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

Comment: Thanks, I will try to set it to 1 second intervals. Regarding the other tags, I already have those, I just didn't think they are relevant.